# Writing to the browser repeats when clicking another button on the page

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a page that has a button:

```
<button id="btnExport1" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 120px;" OnServerClick="btnExport_Click">Export</button>
```

The btnExport_Click method prepares an Excel file which is then sent to browser using the following code

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();

        var attachment = String.Format("attachment; filename=\"SR_ChargeExport_{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.xlsx\"", DateExtensions.CurrentDisplayTime());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(filename);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

        if (deleteFile)
            File.Delete(filename);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

There is also a LinkButton on the page which when clicked runs some javascript on the page to open up a Telerik RadWindow and passes in the url of a new page. On this page there is a LinkButton that looks like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click"><span>Add Comment</span></asp:LinkButton>
```

And in btnUpdate_Click there's some code that basically saves a comment and closes the RadWindow.

The problem I'm having is that after you click the Export button to download a file, if you then add a comment by clicking the button in the RadWindow another Excel file is downloaded. The AddComment code does get run but then the Export code gets run again straight after. I'm thinking it's something to do with not being able to post back to the page after writing to the browser in the Export code.

Answer (score 0):

Make the request for your Excel download be asynchronous via an HTTP Handler, thus you can do this instead:

Markup:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" 
   src="PATH_TO_YOUR\HTTP_HANDLER.ashx">Export</a>
```

ExportToExcelHandler.ashx:

```
public class ExportToExcelHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=excelData.xls");
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        // Put logic here to create Excel download

        // Stream it back to browser

    }

    public bool IsReusable 
    {
        get 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It looks like it could work well but the code that creates the Excel file was using a lot of query string values and I wasn't sure how I would get hold of them in the handler. I found where the present solution was going wrong (see comment).

Comment: @Jim - you can pass query string values to an HTTP Handler just like you do with an `.aspx` page: `HTTPHandler.ashx?id=1&name=jim&type=A`. Inside the HTTP Handler you can read them right of the `Request.QueryString` object like you would in the `Page_Load` of an `.aspx` page.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I found out that there was javascript being run for the OnClientClose event of the RadWindow. In there it was submitting the form (in order to update the comments on the page) so I changed it to do a 'location.reload()' instead.